# C# for and foreach loop difference

Tags: c#

I am using C# 8.0. Given the following code block,

```
    int[] data;
    string str1 = "";
    int size;
    Console.WriteLine("\n Input array size:");
    size = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    if (size >= 1 && size <=9)
    {
      data = new int[size];
      for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
      {
        data[i] = 111 * (i+1);
        foreach (int num in data)
        {
          str1 += "\n data["+i.ToString()+"] =" + num.ToString() + "\n";

        }
        i++;
      }
      Console.WriteLine("{0}", str1);
    }
    else
      Console.WriteLine("Out of range!");
```

I get the following result:

```
Input array size:
3

 data[0] =111

 data[0] =0

 data[0] =0

 data[2] =111

 data[2] =0

 data[2] =333
```

Ideally, I would like output similar to the following:

```
data[0] =111
data[1] =222
data[2] =333
```

May I know how to revise the code, and why?
I've only started learning C# recently.

Edit:

```
if (size >= 1 && size <=9)
    {
      data = new int[size];
      for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
        data[i] = 111 * (i+1);
      foreach (int num in data)
        {
          str1 += "\n data["+i.ToString()+"] = " + num.ToString() + "\n";
          i++;
        }
      Console.WriteLine("{0}", str1);
    }
```

This was the original version from a book, but I was trying to fix the compiling error.

```
main.cs(18,30): error CS0103: The name `i' does not exist i
n the current context
main.cs(19,11): error CS0103: The name `i' does not exist i
n the current context
Compilation failed: 2 error(s), 0 warnings
compiler exit status 1
```

Comment: Remove `i++` from the body of your loop.

Comment: Do you purposely have one of the loops **inside the other one**?

Comment: Use debug (from the menu Debug/Step Over (F10)) to step through your code step by step, and see what is happening.......

Comment: After your edit i can only refer you to the docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/csharp-code-blocks/  

Comment: removing the i++ only the code does not work as required in the question

Comment: Do not use `foreach` if you want to access the index! And, of course, as has been noted from the very start: do not increment the `for` variable as that is being taken care of by the loop! (look at the loop: It has a `i++` right there!)

Answer (score 0):

Your outputs are not really outputting what you add as text inside this inner for-loop. You add output for the full array `data` and all it's indexes but you claim that each `data[index]` is of index `i` - wich it is not. `i` is a number of the outside loop - not the inner loop that constructs the text.

> ```
> foreach (int num in data)
> {
>   // this index you print here is NOT the index it is currently printing
>   // also you print always the full array even those indexes still initialized
>   // to 0 .. thats why you got the 0 outputs
>   str1 += "\n data["+i.ToString()+"] =" + num.ToString() + "\n";
> }
> ```

remove the `for` loop alltogether and simply do

```
str1 += "\n data[" + i.ToString() + "] =" + data[i].ToString() + "\n";
```

---

```
int[] data;
string str1 = "";
int size;
Console.WriteLine("\n Input array size:");
size = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
if (size >= 1 && size <= 9)
{
    data = new int[size];
    for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
    {
        data[i] = 111 * (i + 1);
        str1 += "\n data[" + i.ToString() + "] =" + data[i].ToString() + "\n";
    }

    Console.WriteLine("{0}", str1);
}
else
    Console.WriteLine("Out of range!");
```

to get

```
Input array size:

3

 data[0] =111

 data[1] =222

 data[2] =333
```

Comment: Please find a dictionary for the correct spelling, and meaning, of [conceise](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/concise)

Comment: @luuk changed text

Answer (score 0):

Find the corrected code.
You dont need the 2nd for and the data to be an array. Also add 1 to the i variable (i++) is done by the for loop, so you dont need to do it.
Commented your lines and below the corrected.

```
            // int[] data;
            int data;
            string str1 = "";
            int size;
            Console.WriteLine("\n Input array size:");
            size = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            if (size >= 1 && size <= 9) {
                //data = new int[size];
                //for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++) {
                for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                    //data[i] = 111 * (i + 1);
                    data = 111 * (i + 1);
                    //foreach (int num in data) {
                    // str1 += "\n data[" + i.ToString() + "] =" + num.ToString() + "\n";
                    str1 += "\n data[" + i.ToString() + "] =" + data.ToString() + "\n";
                    //}
                    // i++;
                }
                Console.WriteLine("{0}", str1);
            }
            else
                Console.WriteLine("Out of range!");
```

Output:

[image]